# Sharp rectangular corners in some windows

Tags: 18.04, display, window

Screenshot - 1:

[image]

Screenshot - 2:

[image]

After a recent system update, a few of the windows ( specific apps like files, settings ) in ubuntu-18 tend to have rectangular corners. 
Tried resetting gnome settings. Not working.

Can anyone post a possible fix ?

Comment: You have sharp eyes.

Comment: @PerlDuck Thank you. But this quite annoying for a sharp eyed person.

Comment: An issue like yours is mentioned here http://zeroset.mnim.org/2015/05/03/ubuntu-15-04-vivid-vervet-faulty-rendering-of-rounded-window-corners-in-gnomegtk/ with no solution (switching to another theme is a workaround only). I would try changing the theme to adwaita, purging and reinstalling the theme first: `sudo apt purge light-themes`, then restart, then `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` (probably has been removed removing the themes, and should draw back in the themes). If not, install light-themes manually yourself.

Comment: @vanadium Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after a long time searching and tweaking I realized the issue was with a conflicting gtk.css in `~/home/.config/gtk-3.0` 
It had a border radius property which was messing things up.